# CSS/HTML - DIV doesnt stay aligned to bottom

Tags: html, css

Im new here. I have been working on a site (Still learning).

The sliced PSD is www.primalventures.co.uk/h2

The coded version with CSS and HTML is www.primalventures.co.uk/hammersmith

The second site throws an ugly error on the pages

- Specification
- Amenities
- Recreation

The footer does not stay below the content as you can see on the other pages.

Not sure how to fix the DIV.

```
#footer  {
width: 100%;
height: 130px;
background: grey;
}
```

Thanks,

PV

Comment: Please provide some relevant code

Comment: Hey bud,  welcome.  Do us a favor and add your relevant html and css to the question of even use A fiddle on jsfiddle.Net

Comment: Can you isolate the problem to a simple example? Links to other sites for code tend to get questions closed / deleted (per the guidelines).

Answer (score 0):

You have a broken tag inside your main div (presumably) and the browsers are closing them as an emergency fix. Double check your opening/closing tags are paired.

Comment: I don't see one. If you say that then tell him which element on which site it is ("a broken tag" is like looking for the easter egg)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be in the line

```
<div class="bottom_line"  style="bottom:-200px;">
```

which happens before you include your text. This text is therefore aligned relative to the bottom, and ends up on top of the "footer" (this observed in http://www.primalventures.co.uk/Hammersmith/recreation.html)

Answer (score 0):

The heights of all your div's are all defined in pixels.  If you have more information on certain pages you need to re-define the heights on those pages.  For example, on the recreation page, if you set the "main" div height to 1050px, its fine.

If you wanted the page to automatically re-align depending on the content, you would need to completely redesign the page without defining heights, and instead floating and positioning everything properly.

Answer (score 0):

your element bottom_line and your main-element have a fixed height of 250px and 850px. But you have more text in it. As you use position:absolute for your bottom line, nothing streches over those dimensions. Remove the fixed height and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Add padding-bottom equal to the height of the footer on #main.

```
#main
{
     padding-bottom:200px;
}
```

Here is a link which explains how to structure the html and css to make the footer stick at the bottom. I have used it in my website and it works like a charm!

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page